# ReportExecutionService.Render() - missing hyperlink from report column

Tags: asp.net, excel, reporting-services, hyperlink

I am working on peace of code where, rendering a report using ReportExecutionService.Render() method. I have passed following parameters to this method;

string format = "EXCELOPENXML";

string devInfo = @"False";

Report contains one column with hyperlink, but after rendering the report with Render method, output file is missing that hyperlink. If I export same  report from report viewer to excel, resulting excel has the hyperlink on that column.

What can be the possible issue for missing hyperlink? Do i need to specify any particular format (i tried same thing with HTML, PDF formats as well but no luck)? Is there any workarround to get the hyperlink into the rendered report using ReportExecutionService.Render()?